# Get variable after Hashtag and store it as PHP variable

Tags: javascript, php

I need to get the variable after a hashtag in a URL and store it as a php variable:

www.example.com/lessons.php#!l13

**How would I the #!l13 and store it as a PHP variable?**

I was trying to use **window.location.hash** but do not know how to convert that into a php variable.

Comment: You can't get that with PHP as it is never sent to the server.

Comment: if its your site  just change the urls `/lessons.php?id=l13`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do an AJAX request back to your server. (There are plenty of resources on the web on how to do that.) PHP code is serverside, while `window.location.hash` lives in the browser.

Think of it this way. Your friend is going to go live in another country for a couple of months. You want to know what address he stays at, so you give him instructions. However, he's a bit slow, so you really need to spell things out for him.

What you're trying to do: "Hey, man. When you get there, tell me your address." And he'll complain how you wouldn't be there to hear it.

What you would need to tell him: "Hey, man. When you get there, *pick up the phone, dial my number*, and tell me the address."

Same thing here, you need a request back to server to get any information about the clientside into the PHP land. And if you just do a normal request, your page will reset - which means you should use AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to encode the # as %23, so your URL would look like this:

```
www.example.com?lessons.php%23!113
```

To make it easier, you could use PHP's built-in [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function: 
OR

You can try this

```
var hashStr = location.hash.replace("#","");
```